# Ticks in my animatrion?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Im trying to find the amount of ticks in my animation. My animation is 100 frames long and I am running at 60 fps. How can I figure this out?

Comment: What does "tick" mean in this context?

Comment: Logic ticks, in the logic editor.

Comment: One sure way would be to connect an always sensor in pulse mode to a python module that adds 1 to a `ticks` int var then look at the value of `ticks` when the module exits.

Comment: isn't it one logictick per frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number_of_ticks = (animation_length/animation_fps)*game_fps 
in your case (100/24)*60 = 250

you can set the animation frame rate in the render tab :

[image]

also you can set the game frame rate in the world tab :

[image]